# Electro magnetic wireless electricity

Tags: electromagnetic

I am trying to figure out the size of the coils that I would need to construct to create an electro-magnetic field that would be strong enough to power my device. The device needs at least 1.2V and uses .023A. I am trying to power this device with a spliced USB cords (using the hot wire and the ground wire).

So here is the question, how would you use
 coils to produce a electro-magnetic field to power the device mentioned above?

Comment: Well, what frequency are you going to operate the transformer in? And do you have a H-bridge or something similar to drive the coil?

Comment: At what distance? Unidirectional? Supply Voltage? Current? Frequency?  What are you driving this with?

Comment: Are you allowed to couple the coils with lumps of ferrite or sheets of silicon iron?

Comment: @joshb Ask specific questions, you'll get better answers, provide all relevant information. We don't point people in a better direction, we answer specific questions.

Answer (score 2):

> if someone could point me in the right direction that would be
>   appreciated.

I'd start with this picture in mind: -

[image]

You can assume that the magnetic flux density, at some distance Z, is approximately the same at all points in the area of the receive coil and that gives your total flux (\$\phi\$) entering that coil.

So the induced voltage is \$N\dfrac{d\phi}{dt}\$ where N is the number of turns on the receive coil.

You can use the calculator at [HyperPhysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/curloo.html) to save you a little bit of time. You can enter Z, current and diameter of your transmit coil.

You may find that you need to use two turns or maybe 3 turns to get what you want and, to help things along, it's usually more efficient to parallel tune the transmit coil to get a much bigger current.

Parallel tuning the receive coil is also a bonus for getting more voltage too. Add a bridge rectifier (use fast diodes of course), a smoothing capacitor and a regulator and you are about there.

If things are looking really difficult because of the distances involved I've used litz wire at both ends to improve resonance.